# DeleteCommand not working in asp.net 2.0

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, vb.net

I have the following SqlDataSource:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="LDetails" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:NormCon %>"
    SelectCommand ="SELECT l.Link_ID,l.Link_Name,l.Link_Path,l.Link_Desc
                    FROM HyperLinks l
                    WHERE l.link_id = @Link_ID;"
    UpdateCommand ="UPDATE Hyperlinks SET Link_Name = @Link_Name, Link_Path = @Link_Path, Link_Desc = @Link_Desc WHERE Link_ID = @Link_ID;"
    DeleteCommand ="DELETE FROM Hyperlinks_Groups WHERE Join_Link = @Link_ID; DELETE FROM Hyperlinks WHERE Link_ID = @Link_ID;"
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter Name="Link_ID" ControlID="linkList" PropertyName="SelectedDataKey.Value" />
    </SelectParameters>
    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="Link_Name" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Link_Path" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Link_Desc" />
        <asp:ControlParameter Name="Link_ID" ControlID="linkList" PropertyName="SelectedDataKey.Value" />
    </UpdateParameters>
    <DeleteParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter Name="Link_ID" ControlID="linkList" PropertyName="SelectedDataKey.Value" />
    </DeleteParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

this is the detailsview I have:

```
<asp:DetailsView ID="LinkDetails" runat="server" DataSourceID="LDetails" 
    DataKeyNames="Link_ID" AutoGenerateRows="False" OnItemDeleted="deleteLinkReload" >
    <Fields>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Link_ID" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Link Name">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblLinkName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Link_Name") %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtLinkName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Link_Name") %>' MaxLength="50" /> 
            </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Link">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:HyperLink ID="lnkLinkPath" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Link_Path") %>' NavigateUrl='<%# Bind("Link_Path") %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtLinkActual" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Link_Path") %>' MaxLength="250" /> 
            </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Comment">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblLinkComment" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Link_Desc") %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtLinkComment" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Link_Desc") %>' MaxLength="250" />
            </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="linkDetailsEdit" runat="server" CommandName="edit" Text="Edit" />
                <asp:LinkButton ID="linkDetailsDelete" runat="server" OnClientClick="return confirm('OK to delete link?');" CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete Link" /> <%--OnClick="DeleteLink" --%>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="linkDetailsAccept" runat="server" CommandName="update" Text="Accept" />
                <asp:LinkButton ID="linkDetailsCancel" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" CausesValidation="false" Text="Cancel" />
            </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Fields>
</asp:DetailsView>
```

When I click a delete button in the detailsview which is linked to this, the page refreshes but the item is not deleted.  I think the DeleteCommand is returning 0 rows or erroring without me being able to catch the error.  I've tried seeing if its a case of the DeleteCommand even firing by switching the SQL to this:

```
 DeleteCommand ="INSERT INTO mis_test (string) VALUES ('Hi');"
```

and it still didn't do anything.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try using SQL Server Profiler to see what is run on the database, and what error it gives.

Answer (score 0):

I would bet that your connection string includes things like `User Instance=true` and `AttachDbFileName=...`, and that after you run the delete command, you are connecting via SSMS or Visual Studio (not your app) and checking the table.

If this is the case, then you need to *stop* using this `User Instance` feature (which has been deprecated). What this does is create a copy of your database for each instance of any application that connects.

What you need to do is properly attach your database to a real instance of SQL Server, and connect to that copy of the database from all applications.

Comment: This is my Connection string (with * switching for the server name): <add name="NormCon" connectionString="Data Source=*********;Initial Catalog=BO_Management;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
 It doesn't have the User Instance that you mention :s